# Using an Overdraft method, for a test bank account function

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn Java with no prior coding experience so I am going through a tutorial, however I'm stuck at one part which I can't seem to wrap my head around. For this tutorial, I'm making a mock BankAccount function and trying to test it. However, I am getting stuck on the "setOverdraftAccount" function.

This is my test code:

```
    /**
Class TestBank
**/
//MAKE NO CHANGES TO THIS CLASS OTHER THAN UNCOMMENTING LINES ONE BY ONE
//MODIFY THE BankAccount CLASS TO CORRECT ERRORS REVEALED AS YOU UNCOMMENT THE LINES 
public class TestBank {
    private static int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        BankAccount b1 = new BankAccount(254.36);
        printBalance(b1, 254.36);//must produce "b1 balance = 254.36..."
//         
        double amt = 100.00;
//         
        b1.deposit(amt);
        printBalance(b1, 354.36);//must produce "b1 balance = 354.36..."
//         
        b1.withdraw(100.00);
        printBalance(b1, 254.36);
//        
        BankAccount b2 = new BankAccount(123.45);//must produce "b2 balance = 123.45..."
        printBalance(b2, 123.45);
//         
        b2.deposit(amt*2);
        printBalance(b2, 323.45);
//         
        b2.withdraw(10.56);
        printBalance(b2, 312.89);
//         
        b1.transfer(154.36, b2); //transfer $154.36 from account b1 to account b2
            printBalance(b1, 100.00);
            printBalance(b2, 467.25);
//          
            BankAccount b3 = new BankAccount(83.80);
            printBalance(b3, 83.80); //must produce "b3 balance = 83.80..."
//         
            b1.setOverdraftAccount(b2); // set b2 as the overdraft account for b1
//         //if account balance goes below zero, funds are transferred from overdraft account in $50 increments to cover shortfall
//         
            b2.setOverdraftAccount(b3); //set b3 as the overdraft account for b2
//         
            b1.withdraw(554.50);
            printBalance(b1, 45.50);
            printBalance(b2, 17.25);
            printBalance(b3, 33.80);


    private static void printBalance(BankAccount b, double expectedBalance) 
        {
            counter++;
            System.out.println(counter + ". " +  b.getAccountNumber()+ " balance = "+ b.getBalance() + " --> must be "+ expectedBalance);
        }
}
```

---

```
public class BankAccount {
    private double balance;
    private String accountNumber;
    private static int counter = 1;
    private BankAccount overdraftAccount = null;

    public BankAccount(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
        this.accountNumber = "b"+counter;
        counter++;


    }
    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;

    }
    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void deposit(double amount) {
        balance += amount;
    }
    public void withdraw(double amount) {
        balance -= amount;
    }

    public void transfer(double amount, BankAccount other) {
        this.withdraw(amount);
        other.deposit(amount);
    }

    public void setOverdraftAccount(BankAccount b) {
        overdraftAccount = b;
    }
}
```

On my Testbank class where it says "b1.setOverdraftAccount(b2)" it gives a description of what the program should do when the funds are below 0, in this case add 50$. Could someone point me in the right direction on what I should do to combat this, without adding anything to the TestBank class?

I have a feeling that I should add a while loop into my "setOverdraftAccount" function in order to withdraw 50 from my overdraftaccount but I don't know how to add that 50 into b1's balance.

Comment: Do you know what "over draft" does in the real world?  Can you explain it to us?

Comment: The overdraft withdrawal isn't happening when you set the overdraft account, it happens when the funds reach 0 (at least in the real world). You need to figure out exactly when/where in the program that would happen and add the code there to handle it.

Comment: Please read [mcve].

Comment: @SeanVanGorder Thank you, I figured out my problem was after I gave it more thought. I added more code to my "withdraw" function so if the balance ever gets below 0, I would withdraw money from that balance's overdraft account. Cheers.